# Are racist attitudes correlated with income?

Tags: public-opinion, racism

Although there are plenty of polls that try to ascertain the racial views of different racial and political groups, I can't find any polls that look into the relation, if any, between income and racist attitudes within racial groups. Any help?

Comment: One issue here is that there is no objective measurement of "racism", and for example in the United Stated there is significant controversy on what exactly is and isn't "racism".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker There are some measurable proxies which have been used as an empirical measure of racial bias, which possibly approach objective. Not that there aren't fundamental flaws of course, not least the way in which they results get reported. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit-association_test

Comment: @origimbo - from what I recall (it was podcasts, so no references sorry) even supporters of IAT openly admit that they were unable to establish absolutely any causation between IAT results and observable behavior. That's not [the only criticism of the test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit-association_test#Criticism_and_controversy), but it's pretty devastating one.

Comment: Also, while we're not on Skeptics, an obligatory "correlation != causation" comment seems in order.

Comment: @user4012 The current form of the question seems fairly causation agnostic to me, especially since it isn't even positing a sign for any potential correlation.

Comment: @origimbo - the problem isn't with the question. It's with the people who will read the question and assume correlation = causation - which many people seem to do.

Comment: Anecdotally, my (somewhat rich) grandmother was racist in one way (thinking that races have different skillsets) but not in another (she still agreed on equal human rights). A (poor) acquaintance of mine was the opposite: he conceded that races were not functionally different, but advocated inequality and segregation because of a "my group is the most important" line of thinking. Which one do you consider racist? Are you open to the option that racism exists at all levels of income, but that different _types_ of racism are more predominant with a particular level of income?

Comment: I was born in Ecuador where there was no running water, I've been in The Marine Corps all over the US, raised kids, rented, own homes and now I have tuxedos that are falling apart from all the fund raiser I attend. Racism knows no station because it is part of human instinct springing from tribalism. I would say that sociopaths and autistic people are the only ones I met that are truly un-racist since the part of the brain that is tribal is not functioning. Even among homogenic tribes, each tribe will find something they don't like about another (wrong tartan? wrong hat?)

Comment: Isn't this a question more in the realm of something like sociology rather than politics?

Answer (score 3):

It can be hard to define and measure this without polling multiple questions and having the relevant crosstabs.  I have found one [poll](http://news.gallup.com/poll/149390/Record-High-Approve-Black-White-Marriages.aspx) from Gallup dealing with interracial marriage that has crosstabs based on education.  Since education past high school is correlated very strongly with income, I think we can say that there is a somewhat negative correlation between income and racist beliefs.

[image]

It would of course be best to just have income based crosstabs, I don't think I've ever seen those in a public poll outside of presidential elections though.

Comment: Not directly related to your answer, but I found a really curious data point in your link: the approval level among whites is the same in 2016 as it was among blacks in 2008 (85% vs 84%). Which begs the question of what made the 10% of blacks change the opinion in the last 8 years (Obama presidency offers a plausible hypothesis as the timeline matches)

Comment: The approval of marriage between blacks and whites is not a direct, one-to-one, representation of racism.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - while you are correct, it is definitely a somewhat usable proxy (I don't have a cite, but I personally find it hard to explain opposition to such marriage *as a concept* to be based on anything other than racist sentiment). It's certainly orders of magnitude better than 95% of other proxies popular among progressives most of which amount to "do you support progressive ideology and progressive methods of addressing issues progressives raise? If not it must be because of racism, and not meaningful policy disagreements".

Comment: @user4012 I'm not saying that opposition to it isn't racist. Instead, it is possible to support marriage between blacks and whites, and still be racist.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - ah, ok. I didn't think of type II errors. You're correct. I still maintain that it's a better proxy than most other popular ones, most of which have enormous type I errors.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I did say multiple questions would be better. I think it does help form a floor for racist belief though, and if we reach a further beyond the education/income correlation and posit that a single racist belief positively correlates with other racist beliefs we can sort of get there.

Comment: @user4012 Blacks and white follow the same trendline from 2008 to 2016, especially since the gap has pulled closer compared to previous decades.  Could just be changes in demographics, the question is very strongly correlated to age after all.

Comment: Polls like these are not as meaningful as they appear, because words like "approval" can be interpreted differently. I don't approve of full facial tattoos but I'm not going to try and prohibit them (though I will try to talk a friend out of getting one, up to a point). It's also equally possible for someone  to approve of interracial marriage _even if they hold racist notions_. E.g. if I think of Jews as moneygrabbers (note: I don't) I might still approve my daughter marrying one of those rich bastards. Though often connected, racism and racial intolerance are two different things.

Comment: I appreciate the effort which went into this answer, but I think we can do better than linking an indirect indicator for income to an indirect indicator for racism.

Comment: I'm not sure I read a clear income proxy even. Education is one, but the jump an stall at some college rather than the smoother growth over all education makes me skeptical. And having numbers 90%+ is probably saturation since 5-10% of Americans report believing in lizard people or other far fringe stuff.  Also age correlates with income and inversely with this tolerance.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt The correlation doesn't have to be exactly linear, and high school to college should be the biggest breakpoint, so I don't see why there wouldn't be a jump there.  The point about age is very good, but that actually applies to [wealth](https://dqydj.com/net-worth-by-age-calculator-united-states/) and not [income](https://www.fool.com/retirement/2017/01/02/americans-average-income-by-age-how-do-you-compare.aspx), which isn't what the question asked.  I guess you can you can try to take the age numbers, then look at the income chart and scale it by the population pyramid...

Comment: Or someone (not me) who isn't posting from behind the great firewall can use their superior google-fu to find a poll that just gives us that elusive income crosstab.

Comment: The short, and fairly robust answer is yes, but most of the distinction is mediated by education. Controlling for education, income is not a strong predictor.